# How can I sign out of Skype from everywhere logged in to my account?

Tags: skype, multiple-computers, sign-out

When using Skype, we can log in to the same account from multiple PCs. Currently I have one PC logged into Skype with my account. The problem is that it was a laptop of my relatives and I cannot access it for now.

How can I sign out of Skype from everywhere logged in to my account?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently if you change your password and then sign out this will result in the other session being logged out, see: [How can I get Skype to log out from another location?](http://skype.otherlinks.co.uk/page.asp?id=skype_remote_signout)

> **Change your password to make remote Skype clients sign out**
>
> 1. Go to File | Change Password
> 2. Follow the instructions to change your password.
> 3. Now sign out using File | Sign Out
> 4. Wait a minute or so
> 5. Then sign in again using your new password.
> 6. After a short period of time any remote Skype clients that were logged into your Skype username should stop working. They will require
>      the new password in order to log in again.

Answer (score 38):

According to [the help page of Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-are-chat-commands-and-roles), this will do the trick: just type in any chat window

```
/remotelogout
```

> Sign out all other instances except the current one. This will also stop push notifications on all other instances<sup>[1](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Extreme-online-status-bug/m-p/2989568)</sup>.

To check your current logged in places, run:

```
/showplaces
```

Comment: I doesn't seem to work. I typed it on my PC, and then I typed `/showlocations` and it told me that I'm logged in at one place - this PC. Then, I typed `/showlocations` on my Android phone and it told me that I'm logged in at two places - the phone and the PC.

Comment: In the current Skype version (7.0.0.102) you can use `/showplaces` to list active sessions. The `/remotelogout` still works.

Comment: Using skype 8.83.0.408, ```/remotelogout``` does not work.

Comment: Skype version 8.83.0.409 does not work - "Invalid command, please try again".

Answer (score 1):

/remotelogout This command logs you out from all the other Skype clients that you are currently logged except your current session.

/showplaces This command shows you other instances where the Skype name has currently logged in.

Source: [Skype commands](https://www.techlila.com/skype-commands/)