# Disconnect someone else from my Skype account?

Tags: skype

While my little brother is occupying my desktop he is also occupying my Skype account.
I know about multi login and I am using it, but he keeps sending dirty messages to my friends from the desktop.

Is there any way I can kick him out of Skype?

Comment: Don't save your password to Skype and log out before allowing him use of the desktop. Set up separate user accounts to Windows and change your password (and don't tell him) force him to use his. Smack him around until he learns to keep his hands off your Skype account.

Comment: @Daniel In my mom's eyes, my little brother is a saint. :( I've been grounded for an year last time I put a password. It's too painful.

Comment: Well, here's a social issue that needs fixing before we can fix the technical one. Why would you not be allowed to have your account for yourself? Your brother can do whatever he wants on his account, it doesn't even need to be protected.

Comment: Exactly right @slhck -- to clarify: *Don't lock him out of the computer, just make him use a different user account*. His own. A Windows account that doesn't have access to your Skype account. He doesn't even need a password -- just remember to lock your machine `Windows-L` and he has to click the icon for his own account instead of yours. If you are able to provide Skype chat logs that cannot possibly be yours (e.g. while away from home, e.g. school, sports), have them ready in case he won't accept you wanting some privacy (depending on your family situation, of course).

Comment: @Daniel She doesn't care -_- Anyway, I understand there is no way to kick him out... Is it?

Answer (score 4):

A few solutions (considering the restrictions in the comments):

- Remember to sign out of skype (and don't remember password) every time you leave the computer
- Change your Skype password each time you think your little brother may be using it (this will force all other logged in clients to log out)
- Add a schedule task to kill the Skype process during times that you are normally not home. You can use a batch file to test for (the contents of) a file before killing the process. Each time you are at the computer, just create that special file.
- Create a separated account with password on your computer and always run Skype as that user.

  [image]

  You may need to find someway to [hide that account from welcome screen](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=&q=hide+account+from+welcome+screen) so your parents don't know.
- You can also create your own personal account and hide it like in the previous method. Before Vista, you'll need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> twice at the welcome screen to log-in as that user. In Vista or later systems, just select other user and type the user name.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the rest that you should not save your password if you are having such issues.
Also if you are at some other location and you know that he is logged into your account just change the password at your end , this should log him off and also stop him from loggin in again (unless he also has your email password :P )

Answer (score 0):

On Skype chat, type

```
/remotelogout
```

and hit send.

Comment: Interesting – do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I readed it on http://superuser.com/questions/346136/how-can-i-sign-out-of-skype-from-everywhere-logged-in-to-my-account and tried it myself.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes it a duplicate of the other question though.